# how to merge excel cell in vsto

Tags: excel

I am trying to merge two cell of excel row, it works but when I insert a new column and than trying to merge row cell including new column cell it does not and I required to insert a new column what should I do?

```
Range rgSum = UsedArea.Cells[i, cellnum];
rgSum.EntireColumn.Insert();
Range rgSum2 = UsedArea.Cells[i,cellnum+1];                                           
Range RgFinal = sheet.get_Range(rgSum, rgSum2);
RgFinal.Merge();
```